# Java: Is child overriding parent discouraged?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I was wondering if it's frowned upon that when designing an framework to be used by others, a class has some function as default behavior and expects its customers to override it if necessary. An example would be something like the following:

```
public class RecordProcessor<T extends Record> {
    // ...
    public void process() {
        // process record logic
    }
}
```

Consumers of this library creates their concrete classes to process their own records of type `T`.

Now I want to add a function called `preProcess()` to offer the ability for the consumers to preprocess their records. It would then look something like this:

```
public class RecordProcessor<T extends Record> {
    // ...
    public void process() {
        preprocess();
        // process record logic
    }

    public void preProcess() {
        // By default no preprocessing
    }
}
```

I know I can make `preProcess` an abstract function, but I dont want to due to a couple reasons:

1. Not all customers need to preprocess their records
2. We have a pipeline structure that autodeploys pushed code, so making `RecordProcessor` an abstract class would immediately break our customers' applications.

Is making `preProcess` do nothing in the parent class and let child classes override it considered bad practice? If not, what should the best way be to let customers know that they now have the power to preprocess the records? Through java docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing- which I also thought was pretty good, inspired by @tsolakp, was simply creating a child class to `RecordProcessor`, called something like `PreprocessRecordProcessor`. This has no way of interfering existing code because nothing existing was touched. The class would something like this:

```
public class PreprocessRecordProcessor<T extends Record> extends RecordProcessor<T> {
    // ...
    public void process() {
        preProcess();
        super.process();
    }

    protected abstract void preProcess();
}
```

And if customers of this library would like to add their own logic they can simply extend this class and they'd be *forced* to provide pre-processing logic (as supposed to having the option to provide, which may result in unexpected results if they forgot to.)

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to mark the public method as final (but this might also break existing apps) and allow protected hook methods to be overridden.  For example:

```
public class RecordProcessor<T extends Record> {
    // ...
    public final void process() {
        doPreProcess();
        doProcess();
        doPostProcess();
    }

    protected void doPreProcess() {
        // By default no preprocessing
        return;
    }

    protected void doProcess() {
        // some default implementation
    }

    protected void doPostProcess() {
       // By default no postprocessing
       return;
    }
}
```

Having some documentation should make it natural for other developers to recognize the optional extension methods.

I don't see anything wrong with having a hook method which does nothing.  However, it should contain a return statement so static analysis tools won't complain.

UPDATE:  in order to avoid breaking existing apps, if possible mark the existing method as deprecated and introduce a new method.  For example:

```
public class RecordProcessor<T extends Record> {
    // ...

    public final void execute() {
        doPreProcess();
        doProcess();
        doPostProcess();
    }

    @Deprecated - use execute() method instead.
    public void process() {
        doProcess();
    }

    protected void doPreProcess() {
        // By default no preprocessing
        return;
    }

    protected void doProcess() {
        // some default implementation
    }

    protected void doPostProcess() {
       // By default no postprocessing
       return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, and it makes sense to me too. But probably not deprecate process since again, consumers might not necessarily need the `preProcess` call so it'd still make sense to keep `process` around?

Comment: The deprecation was just to avoid breaking existing apps which might already be overriding `process()`.  If that is not an issue then it would probably be best to mark it as final which avoids the deprecation.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer composition over inheritance. If you want your clients to add custom pre processing then do it by delegating to a separate objects.

```
    public interface RecordPreProcessor<T extends Record>{
        public void process(T record);
    }

    public class RecordProcessor<T extends Record> {
        private RecordPreProcessor<T> recordPreProcessor = null;         

        public void setRecordPreProcessor(RecordPreProcessor<T> recordPreProcessor) {
            this.recordPreProcessor = recordPreProcessor;
        }

        public void process() {
            if (recordPreProcessor != null) recordPreProcessor.process(record);
            // process record logic
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, overriding is not discouraged in Java.

- The language **allows** overriding.
- The language makes all methods overridable **by default**.
- The Java class library includes examples of the same pattern.

Your approach is one reasonable way to allow subclasses to extend the behavior of their parent class. There are alternatives, such as passing a behavior as an object. However, there is no one true way.

One way you could improve your code is to mark preProcess() as **protected**. It's an implementation detail of the class. You don't want just anyone holding a RecordProcessor to decide they can call preProcess() by itself, right?

```
public class RecordProcessor<T extends Record> {
  ... 
  protected void preProcess() {
  ^^^^^^^^^
    // By default no preprocessing
  }
}
```

Another way to improve this is to consider whether you intend anyone to create an instance of the superclass RecordProcessor. If you don't, make the class **abstract**, to prevent that. The class name can express that, if you like, or your coding guidelines call for it.

```
public abstract class AbstractRecordProcessor<T extends Record> {
       ^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^
  ... 
  protected void preProcess() {
    // By default no preprocessing
  }
}
```

One common way to document such methods is with the phrase **"The default implementation does nothing. Subclasses may override this method ..."**. For example, below is the documentation for `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.done()`. You can find more examples by searching for the first sentence of that phrase online.

```
public class FutureTask<V> implements RunnableFuture<V> {
  ...
  /**
   * Protected method invoked when this task transitions to state
   * {@code isDone} (whether normally or via cancellation). The
   * default implementation does nothing.  Subclasses may override
   * this method to invoke completion callbacks or perform
   * bookkeeping. Note that you can query status inside the
   * implementation of this method to determine whether this task
   * has been cancelled.
   */
  protected void done() { }
}
```

Comment: I by no mean meant overriding should be discouraged, I was more curious about the right way (or convention) of updating libraries while avoiding breaking existing customer code at the same time. Child overriding parent being *allowed* doesn't automatically mean it's the *best* approach in every scenario right? My concern was having a "default" behaviour which developers wouldn't know at compile time, unless they drill into the source code, or read the documentation.